# Excel VBA - Check if character equal to symbols

Tags: vba, excel, char, symbols

I'm trying to check whether my selection of text in excel contains superscripts and symbols like **`®™º`**. I managed to find the way to check for superscript as below.

```
For Each c In rngSel
lChar = Len(c.Value)
    For lCount = 1 To lChar
        With c.Characters(lCount, 1).Font

            'Superscript
            If .Superscript Then
            str_Test = str_Test & "" & lCount
            isFlag = "Y"
            .ColorIndex = 3
            total_super_count = total_super_count + 1
```

Any idea how I can check whther the character equals to symbols as highlighted as above. Any suggestion or references link is highly appreciated.

**EDITED**

```
Columns("A:S").Select
Rows("1:50").Select
Set rngSel = Selection
For Each c In rngSel
lChar1 = Len(c.Value)
    'For lCount = 1 To lChar
     '   With c.Characters(lCount, 1).Font
     For lCount1 = 1 To c.Characters.Count
     With c.Characters(lCount1, 1)


            'Test the character
            If .Text Like "°" Then
count_symbol = count_symbol + 1
            'Do something
                .Font.Color = vbRed

            End If
        End With
    Next lCount1
Next c
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for those particular characters, you just loop through each character and compare to your list of symbols for which you are searching.  e.g:

---

```
For Each C In R
    For I = 1 To C.Characters.Count
        With C.Characters(I, 1)

            'Test the character
            If .Text Like "[®™º]" Then

            'Do something
                .Font.Color = vbRed

            End If
        End With
    Next I
Next C
```

---

You should note that the particular symbols you show above that you are looking for will show font.superscript = FALSE as they are already "above the line" by virtue of the nature of the character itself.

Comment: it throw me error like the screen shot in my question.

Comment: @chinna_2 Then look for a problem in your unposted code where you set R and C to your desired ranges.

Comment: getting error here. ` For lCount = 1 To c.Characters.Count`

Comment: added the screen shot with C

Comment: @chinna_82 that screenshot does not show what is in C. I do not see the properties or the contents. I suspect C is empty. If that is the reason for your error, just check to make sure there is something in C before proceeding with the subsequent code.

Comment: I've added on error and do next but, having performance issue now. The code stuck in middle and excel not responding. Working on it.

Comment: @chinna_82. I see no reason for using an **On Error** statement.  And I am not aware of **do next**. What does that do?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `chr` value of the character, something like `Asc(character)`

If you review http://www.gtwiki.org/mwiki/?title=VB_Chr_Values you'll see the list of `chr` values.

Simply, loop through all characters of the string and get the `chr` value, and if it's above 122 then it's a symbol!

Also note, there may be a few other characters (below 122) you want to check for, so do review the list in full. EG, from 0 to 47 !

So, in my Excel sheet, A1 has the value `5™B`

This does what you want

```
Sub DetectSymbols()

Dim val As String
val = Range("A1").Value                 'Get value or walk the plank !

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(val)                   'Loop through each character in string, ya sea dogs
    Dim c As String
    c = Mid(val, i, 1)  
    Dim chrVal As Integer
    chrVal = Asc(c)
    If (chrVal > 122) Then              'Only checking > 122 to keep it simple
        MsgBox (c & " is a symbol")     'Aye aye, captain, we found the treasure!
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: this working fine, but it only check for A1. How do I change if I want to get the selection. I tried Range("A1","C10") and its not working. Please advice.

Comment: @chinna_82, just loop through? 
Set rng = Range("A1:A3") 
For Each cell In rng
Next cell

Comment: i have updated the question with your suggestion, throw me **Invalid procedure call or arguement** at `c = Mid(cell,i,1)`